# Failed to save PowerBIReportsComponent.design: null: Source Lightning component save error

Tags: apex, lightning

i wrote a component, and a .design file for it.

that's the .design file:

```
<design:component >
    <design:attribute name="defaultSearch" label="Default Search" default="Restaurants" description="What would you like to search for?" />
</design:component>
```

that's the component:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,force:hasSObjectName">
        <aura:attribute name="tab1" type="String" />
        <aura:attribute name="tab2" type="String" />
        <aura:attribute name="tab3" type="String" />
        <aura:attribute name="tab4" type="String" />
        <aura:attribute name="tab5" type="String" />
        <aura:attribute name="tab6" type="String" />
        <aura:attribute name="tab7" type="String" />


       <lightning:tabset class="slds-tabs_card slds-tabs_default">
        <lightning:tab class="slds-tabs_default__item">
            <aura:set attribute="label">
                Potential CrossSell Report
                <!--lightning:icon iconName="utility:connected_apps"/-->
            </aura:set>

            <iframe src="http://something.com" width="100%" height="900" style="overflow: hidden;"/>

        </lightning:tab>
         <lightning:tab >
            <aura:set attribute="label">
                Item Two
            </aura:set>
        </lightning:tab>
        <lightning:tab >
            <aura:set attribute="label">
                Item Three
            </aura:set>
        </lightning:tab>
    </lightning:tabset>   
</aura:component>
```

when i try to save the design file i receive the error:
FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION: Failed to save PowerBIReportsComponent.design: null:Source

i have no idea why it occurs, and couldn't find any answers on it.

Comment: Design attribute name should match with any attributes in the component

Comment: youre correct, i didnt know that. please write it as an answer so i can accept it :)

Comment: sure...........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bug is Design attribute name should match with any attributes in the component.

Example:

**Design:**

```
<design:component >
    <design:attribute name="defaultSearch" label="Default Search" default="Restaurants" description="What would you like to search for?" />
</design:component>
```

**Component:**

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,force:hasSObjectName">
        <aura:attribute name="defaultSearch" type="String" />
</aura:component>
```